# Динамическое изменение аргумента интерфэйса Retrofit2

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

Есть метод для изменения услуги:

```
    @Multipart
    @PUT("/api/edit/service/{service_id}/{master_id}")
    Observable<SimpleBody> editService(@Path("service_id") String serviceId,
                                     @Path("master_id") String userId,
                                     @Part MultipartBody.Part avatar,
                                     @Part("title") RequestBody title,
                                     @Part("price") RequestBody price,
                                     @Part("description") RequestBody description,
                                     @Part("period") RequestBody periodInMinutes,
                                     @Part("service_category") RequestBody serviceCategory)
```

в котором я должен отправлять то поле которое изменилось, либо все поля, включая изменившееся поле. То есть в выше написанном методе я отправляю все поля.

Но я хочу отправлять только то поле, которое изменилось, типа так:

```
Observable<SimpleBody> editService(@Path("service_id") String serviceId,
                                     @Path("master_id") String userId,
                                     @Part("title") RequestBody title)
```

Только в данном случае я отправляю я отправляю измененный заголовок, так как в аннотации `@Part` прописал ключ заголовка - `@Part("title")`. 
Таким образом мне придется для каждого поля создать отдельный метод. Мне кажется это не правильно.

Так вот, возможно ли отправлять все измененные поля с ключами, а в методе `editService()` прописать типа:

```
Observable<SimpleBody> editService(@Path("service_id") String serviceId,
                                     @Path("master_id") String userId,
                                     @Part RequestBody service)
```

Может есть решение как скомпоновать поля в один?

Comment: Вроде как во время исполнения без рефлексии в аннотациях ничего изменить не получится. Возможно, если вы посмотрите в каком в итоге виде отправляются данные запроса вы сможете этот запрос немного иначе сделать. Например, если вы в итоге JSON отправляете, то можно его самостоятельно сформировать с нужными полями и отправить

Comment: Если правильно понял, то я не отправляю `Json` а `form-data type`, где есть поле для изображения типа `MultipartBody.Part`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил задачу с помощью `@PartMap` В `RetrofitServiceApi`:

```
@Multipart
@PUT("/api/edit/service/{service_id}/{master_id}")
Observable<SimpleBody> editService(@Path("service_id") String serviceId,
                                   @Path("master_id") String userId,
                                   @PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> params);
```

И отправляю:

```
String image = serviceModel.getImage();
String title = serviceModel.getTitle();
String description = serviceModel.getDescription();
String period = serviceModel.getPeriod();
int price = serviceModel.getPrice();

if (!tmpServiceClick.getImage().equals(image)) {
     parameters.putAll(RetrofitRequestUtil.fileToRequestBodyMap(file, "avatar"));
}
if (!tmpServiceClick.getTitle().equals(title)) {
     parameters.put("title", RetrofitRequestUtil.toRequestBody(title));
}
if (!tmpServiceClick.getDescription().equals(description)) {
     parameters.put("description", RetrofitRequestUtil.toRequestBody(description));
}
if (!tmpServiceClick.getPeriod().equals(period)) {
     parameters.put("period", RetrofitRequestUtil.toRequestBody(period));
}
if (tmpServiceClick.getPrice() != price) {
    parameters.put("price", RetrofitRequestUtil.toRequestBody(String.valueOf(price)));
}

retrofitInterface.editService(masterId, serviceModel.getPublicId(), parameters))
```

Класс `RetrofitRequestUtil`:

```
public static RequestBody toRequestBody(String value) {
    return RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), value);
}
```